# Can't mount encrypted HFS volume

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, encryption, core-storage

I have an external hard drive that is partitioned as a single encrypted HFS+ volume.

Here's what's going on: 
The volume won't mount, Disk Utility won't repair it.

`diskutil cs list` says:

[image: Diskutil CS List says:]

However:

```
diskutil coreStorage unlockVolume 042F9672-CEEC-47D3-8749-4D4F5A52B6CE -stdinpassphrase
```

returns

`042F9672-CEEC-47D3-8749-4D4F5A52B6CE is already unlocked and is attached as disk5`

and

```
diskutil mount disk5
```

returns

```
disk5 is a CoreStorage Logical Volume which failed to mount
```

Other things i tried:

```
diskutil cs decryptVolume 042F9672-CEEC-47D3-8749-4D4F5A52B6CE
```

Which returned

```
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 042F9672-CEEC-47D3-8749-4D4F5A52B6CE
Started CoreStorage operation on disk5 Cairo
Scheduling decryption of Core Storage Logical Volume
Core Storage LV UUID: 042F9672-CEEC-47D3-8749-4D4F5A52B6CE
Finished CoreStorage operation on disk5 Cairo
```

But now my `diskutil cs list` looks like this and it has for an hour.

[image: But now my diskutil cs list looks like this]

I'm lost, i'm stuck, i'd need help.

Comment: thanks, four hours later i'm actually at 2%. mount didn't work but i can't replicate the error message for you here.

Comment: ah, just listing, not mounting. yeah disk doesn't show there.

Comment: after conversion going up to about 6% `diskutil cs list` now tells me  Conversion Progress:   Paused

Comment: yeah thanks, somehow it worked again. it's excruciatingly slow (gained 2 percent overnight) but it seems to work

Comment: You may have to disable sleep/turn off "Put hard disk to sleep when possible"/disable separate sleep functions provided by third-party tools (I think some e.g. Western Digital tools/drivers for WD drives enable it)